# d3.select versus document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

I am having trouble getting a transition to work because the d3.select() method is not working. I've found a workaround by using document.getElementId() and applying the change by manually changing the attributes of the selected DOM element. Everything displays just fine in the browser, so I went to the console to do some investigating.

What I found was that in console, when I type

```
document.getElementId("elementId")
```

it returns the DOM element as expected, but when I use

```
d3.select("#elementId")
```

or

```
d3.select("elementId")
```

it returns the following object:

```
>pt {_groups: Array[1], _parents: Array[1]}
```

Could somebody who knows more about this explain what is going on and how to get d3.select to return the actual DOM object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`d3.select("#elementId")` returns a **D3 selection** (which since D3 v4.x is an object instead of an array), not the DOM element. That's the expected behaviour.

To get the actual DOM element, use the method `node()`:

```
d3.select("#elementId").node();
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var node = d3.select("#foo").node();
var selection = d3.select("#foo");
console.log("node: ", node)
console.log("selection: ", selection)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<p id="foo">This is a paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Doing that returns null, even though the element exists.

Comment: @thewayup nope, it does not return null. Check the console: https://jsfiddle.net/ehmuro5y/

Comment: Well, you can see clearly in the fiddle and in the demo above that it **does not** returns `null`. You have other problem somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, I solved it by using d3.select("path#elementID"). For whatever reason it doesn't want to select when just using by elementID

Comment: This is **not** correct (someone even downvoted your answer). Are you sure you have just **one** ID in that page? IDs have to be unique.

Comment: How is it not correct when it worked? The IDs are all unique.

Comment: Well, unless you provide an [MCVE] reproducing the behaviour, there is nothing more I can do.

Comment: @thewayup Don't get Gerardo wrong: this is meant to challenge you, not to embarrass you! If you are really able to set up a demo backing your assumption that selecting by the ID alone will not work, I really encourage you to share it with the community as it might prove really interesting.

Comment: Gerardo's tip is working. Don't know what changed after I rebooted my computer, but I'm accepting his answer since that does the trick now.